# jQuery find form element type

Tags: jquery

How to find out form element type by its name using jQuery. For example I have code below which set values for form elements. For edit boxes I will use first code and for radio buttons  second code, but before accessing elements with code below I need to find out what type form element is.

Code #1

```
$("[" + attr + "='" + _name + "']", this).val(value);
```

Code #2

```
$("[" + attr + "='" + _name + "']", this).filter("[value=" + value + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var type = $("[" + attr + "='" + _name + "']", this).attr("type");
```

You would then be able to use an `if`/`else` or a `switch` to execute the correct code based on the value of the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do -

Code #1

```
$("input:text[" + attr + "='" + _name + "']", this).val(value);
```

Code #2

```
$("input:checkbox[" + attr + "='" + _name + "']", this).filter("[value=" + value + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
```

This should allow you to run both statements without using any 'if' functionality.